# MySQL UTC Date format

Tags: python, mysql, twitter, utc

I am pulling data from Twitter's API and the return date is UTC in the following form:

> Sat Jan 24 22:14:29 +0000 2009

Can MySQL handle this format specifically or do I need to transform it?  I am pulling the data using Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you are not willing to transform it in Python, MySQL can handle this with the [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function, as in the following example:

```
INSERT INTO
    your_table
VALUES ( 
    STR_TO_DATE('Sat Jan 24 22:14:29 +0000 2009', '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s +0000 %Y')
);
```

You may also want to check the full list of possible format specifiers: [MySQL: DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function%5Fdate-format).

Comment: Thats great! What do you recommend the data format be in MySQL and if I wanted to, best way to do this in Python prior to MySQL import?  Thanks again.